# How to show the actual item's index in datatacle?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, drag-and-drop, webix

In my app, I need to show the index of the data entry in the first datatable column and it must work after DnD (so I suppose the column should be dynamically refreshed). But how is it possible in Webix datatable?

For now, I am able to get the index manually using `getIndexById`, but this method doesn't work in the column template. For instance:

```
/* inside the config */
  drag:true, 
  columns:[    
    { id:"index", template:function(obj){
      console.log(obj.id);
      // doesn't work:
      // console.log(datatable.getIdByIndex(obj.id)); 
    } },
    { id:"id" },       
    { 
      id:"title", fillspace:true, sort:"string"     
    }
  ],
  ready:function(){
    this.eachRow( 
      function (row){ 
        console.log( this.getIndexById(row) ) // works
      }
    ) 
  }
});

/* somewhere else */
console.log(datatable.getIdByIndex(4));
```

[Code sample](http://webix.com/snippet/7ce5e9fe).

Is this possible at all? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the index of row (data entry) you must define your index template as:

```
template: function(obj){
    return $$("dt").getIndexById(obj.id); }
```

where "dt" is the id of your datatable. It automatically changes the index when you perform any DnD operation. Further, check the snippet [here](http://webix.com/snippet/3029c2f2).

Comment: Oh my, it was just my terrible mistake as I've tried the opposite method (/__-;) I'm wondering whether I should delete this topic, but thank you anyway!